# Which function in glibc calls the main function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc

I am trying to understand how Linux launches a program. I read somewhere that some function in glibc calls the main function. Profiling with callgrind and looking at the call-graphs in Kcachegrind, I see `below main` which calls main. But I don't understand this, a function can't be named such. So my question is which function in the glibc actually starts the main function.

Comment: __libc_start_main() I think,

http://linuxgazette.net/issue84/hawk.html

Comment: [`__libc_start_main`](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html) defined in the Linux Standard Base.

Comment: Also check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668913/elf-binary-compiled-by-gcc-what-happens-from-entry-point-to-main and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524826/linux-is-it-possible-to-write-a-working-program-that-does-not-rely-on-the-libc

Comment: `below main` is not a function; it is an annotation of the stack trace indicating the division between the program's stack and uninteresting housekeeping stack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following valgrind's own help you'll find this explanation for the option *--show-below-main*:

> By default, stack traces for errors do not show any functions that
>   appear beneath main because most of the time it's uninteresting C
>   library stuff and/or gobbledygook. Alternatively, if main is not
>   present in the stack trace, stack traces will not show any functions
>   below main-like functions such as glibc's __libc_start_main.
>   Furthermore, if main-like functions are present in the trace, they are
>   normalised as (below main), in order to make the output more
>   deterministic.

As such, **below main** is not the function which calls main itself, but **__libc_start_main**.